# Postgresql SELECT item from JSONB array - array as top-level json object

Tags: postgresql, json

I have JSONB column which stores the data in this format

```
[
    {
        "item1": "value1",
        "item2": "value2"
    },
    {
        "item1": "value3",
        "item2": "value4"
    }
]
```

I am trying to select 'item1' with query

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data)->'item1' FROM test_table
```

Error I am getting is:

```
cannot extract elements from an object
```

How should I change the query to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unnest the array elements to rows in the `from` clause:

```
select i.dt -> 'item1' as item1
from test_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.data) as i(dt)
```